# Multiple inputs are needed for a basic calculator before resetting

Tags: python, pycharm, user-input, calculator

My program is almost complete but I can't seem to allow the...

"Would you like to do more calculations? Enter (Y) for yes, or any ""other character for no. "

...output from going through without first entering my selection (e.g. "Y" or any other character") numerous times.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEYtj.png)

I would really appreciate some help!

```
"""My First Program!!!"""

# Modules:

import time     # Provides time-related functions


# Delayed text to give it a "Turing" feel

def calculator_print(*args, delay=1):
    print(*args)
    time.sleep(delay)

# Operations:


def add(num1, num2):
    #   Returns the sum of num1 and num2
    return num1 + num2


def sub(num1, num2):
    #   Returns the difference of num1 and num2
    return num1 - num2


def mul(num1, num2):
    #   Returns the product of num1 and num2
    return num1 * num2


def div(num1, num2):
    #   Returns the quotient of num1 and num2
    try:
        return num1 / num2
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        # Handles division by zero
        calculator_print("Division by zero cannot be done. You have broken the universe. Returning zero...")
        return 0


def exp(num1, num2):
    #   Returns the result of num1 being the base and num2 being the exponent
    return num1 ** num2


# Run operational functions:

def run_operation(operation, num1, num2):
    # Determine operation
    if operation == 1:
        calculator_print("Adding...\n")
        calculator_print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
    elif operation == 2:
        calculator_print("Subtracting...\n")
        calculator_print(num1, "-", num2, "=", sub(num1, num2))
    elif operation == 3:
        calculator_print("Multiplying...\n")
        calculator_print(num1, "*", num2, "=", mul(num1, num2))
    elif operation == 4:
        calculator_print("Dividing...\n")
        calculator_print(num1, "/", num2, "=", div(num1, num2))
    elif operation == 5:
        calculator_print("Exponentiating...\n")
        calculator_print(num1, "^", num2, "=", exp(num1, num2))
    else:
        calculator_print("I don't understand. Please try again.")


def main():
    # Ask if the user wants to do more calculations or exit:
    def restart(response):
                    # uses "in" to check multiple values,
                    # a replacement for (response == "Y" or response == "y")
                    # which is longer and harder to read.
        if response in ("Y", "y"):
            return True
        else:
            calculator_print("Thank you for calculating with me!")
            calculator_print("BEEP BOOP BEEP!")
            calculator_print("Goodbye.")
            return False

# Main functions:

    #  Title Sequence
    calculator_print('\n\nThe Sonderfox Calculator\n\n')
    calculator_print('     ----LOADING----\n\n')
    calculator_print('Hello. I am your personal calculator. \nBEEP BOOP BEEP. \n\n')
    while True:  # Loops if user would like to restart program
        try:
            # Acquire user input
            num1 = (int(input("What is number 1? ")))
            num2 = (int(input("What is number 2? ")))
            operation = int(input("What would you like to do? \n1. Addition, 2. Subtraction, 3. Multiplication, "
                                  "4. Division, 5. Exponentiation \nPlease choose an operation: "))
        except (NameError, ValueError):  # Handles any value errors
            calculator_print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
            return
        run_operation(operation, num1, num2)
        # Ask if the user wants to do more calculations or exit:
        restart_msg = input("Would you like to do more calculations? Enter (Y) for yes, or any "
                            "other character for no. ")
        if not restart(str(input(restart_msg))):  # uses the function I wrote
            return


main()
```

Comment: You're asking for whether the user wants to restart twice.

Comment: Look at how you are using input. Why are you using `input` again in `if not restart(str(input(restart_msg))):`?

Comment: `restart_msg = input("Would you like to do more calculations? Enter (Y) for yes, or any other character for no. ")
    if not restart(restart_msg):
    return`

I've tried that but my output still ended up like this:

`Would you like to do more calculations? Enter (Y) for yes, or any other character for no. [Y]
Y[Y]
What is number 1?`

...where the Y in brackets signifies a user input. I have to press the return key multiple times to get the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is really your first program, that's truly impressive!

So, I've pasted the code we want to focus on below:

```
restart_msg = input("Would you like to do more calculations? Enter (Y) for yes, or any other character for no. ")
if not restart(str(input(restart_msg))):  # uses the function I wrote
    return   # Stop the program
```

In the first line, the computer prompts for an input with "Would you like to do more calculations?" (and so on). It then stores that first input in the variable `restart_msg`. Then, in the second line, you call `restart(str(input(restart_msg)))`. Since that contains a call to `input()` and passes `restart_msg` as the only parameter, the computer prompts for an input by outputting whatever you just entered. It stores that entry in a string, and passes it to `restart()`.

It seems like this is your intention in the second line:

```
if not restart(str(restart_msg)):
```

That way, the computer converts the first input you entered to a string by passing it through `str()`, and passes that through your restart function.

This is a pretty ambitious project, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for an input of an input. restart_msg = input() and then you do input(restart_msg).

Also note that there's no need to transform the input to string with str() as in python3 input() already returns a string.